# Get an array of int from a String of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, int

I have a long string of numbers,

```
String strNumbers = "123456789";
```

I need to get an `int[]` from this.

I use this method to get it:

```
public static int[] getIntArray(strNumbers)
{
    String[] strValues = strNumbers.split("");
    int[] iArr = new int[strValues.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < strValues.length; i++)
    {
        iArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strValues[i]);
    }
    return iArr;
}
```

I get this error : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

My guess is that I cannot split a String that way. I tried all sorts of escape or Regex but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

Comment: thanks for the editing. I will get it right some day. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the split regex. Try this instead:

```
String[] strValues = strNumbers.split("(?<=\\d)");
```

This splits after every digit (using a *look behind* regex), which will create an array of size zero for blank input.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. I am kind of new to regex but I am getting there.

Comment: You're welcome :) I can recommend [this site](http://regular-expressions.com/refadv.html) as a good regex reference site.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
char[] chars = strNumbers.toCharArray();
```

and then iterate through the `char` array.

Comment: This is a good idea, I feel a bit stupid because I did not think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use charAt() function to retrieve each character in the string and then do the parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a for loop going through your string and calling `String.charAt(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
char[] chars = strNumbers.toCharArray();
int[] iArr = new int[chars.length];
for(int i = 0 ; i < chars.length ; ++i) {
    iArr[i] = chars[i] - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop statement to iterate the string. And then you use a substring method to chop the string into individual number. Using the substring() method you can define the length of the substring to be converted into number.